# How to display a full name instead of an user name when opening a shared file?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

When one of my users tries to open a file in Office 2007 he gets a massage "This file can only be opened in read-only mode; blocked by 'another user'. The user doesn't know who 'another user' is. As an admin I know who the full name of the user that holds the file. Can the user get a massage about who hold the file with a full name instead of an user name.

Does anyone have an idea?